# Not being able to inject Mediatr into multiple assemblies

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, mediatr

I am doing a microservice oriented project and i am Adding Mediatr to the Service lawyer but It throws an exception saying there werent any assemblies to scan(I suppose it doesnt find it?)

in Program.cs I have the following

```
var assemblies = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Where(x=>x.FullName.Contains("service")).ToList();
builder.Services.AddMediatR(cfg => { 

    assemblies.Select(assembly => cfg.RegisterServicesFromAssembly(assembly));
});
```

Comment: Have you tried to use `builder.Services.AddMediatR(assemblies )` directly?